# Nullpointer Exception and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

Consider the following code:

```
class Chicks {
       synchronized void yack(long id) {
                       for(int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
                                   System.out.print(id + " ");
                                   Thread.yield();
                        }
       }
}
public class ChicksYack implements Runnable {
      Chicks c;                                //.....(1)
      public static void main(String[] args) {
                       new ChicksYack().go();
      }
      void go() {
                      c = new Chicks();        //........(2)
                      new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
                      new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
      }
      public void run() {
                      c.yack(Thread.currentThread().getId());
      }
}
```

When i run this code, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception that I have not initialized variable c. But didn't i initialized it at line ....(2)? I am having trouble getting this concept. Does threading has a part to play in this exception?

Comment: Which line gives the NPE?

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
new Thread(new ChicksYack()).start();
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The attribute `c` of the newly created `ChicksYack` object is never initialized. In the `go()` method you only initialize `c` for the current (`this`) object.

That's why you get an NPE in the `run()` method. A good solution would be to initialize that variable in a default constructor for `ChicksYack`.

Comment: Or even better, just initialise it at the point of declaration (since it doesn't require any external state).

Answer (score 0):

In the `go()` method, you're instantiating two new `ChickYack` objects, which have a null `c`. You should put the `c = new Chicks()` in your `ChicksYack` constructor.